# CRM Javascript RetrieveMultiple from M:M entity

Tags: javascript, many-to-many, entity, crm

I need to retrieve fields from all related records into a parent entity. I have got it working in a 1:M relationship, however I can't figure out how to get it working for a M:M relationship, because there is no relationship ID. I need to complete this through javascript. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this I used an IFRAME and displayed the data through the IFRAME instead pulling CRM information through the query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of (presumably) Microsoft Dynamics CRM you are using. I am going to assume you are using 2011. I'm also not fully clear on what you are specifically trying to acheive, but maybe this will help.

CRM 2011 provides an OData endpoint. [This blog posting](http://crmscape.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/crm-2011-odata-json-and-crm-forms.html) by Mark Kovalcson describes how it can be used.

To get the name and post code of an Account, you would use something like this as your select query:

```
http://crmserver/MyOrgName/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet(guid'5B19D04F-C48E-E111-92D4-00155D107003')?$select=Name,Address1_PostalCode
```

If you wanted to see all instances of child records via the N:N relationship with leads (called accountleads_association) you would use:

```
http://crmserver/MyOrgName/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet(guid'5B19D04F-C48E-E111-92D4-00155D107003')/accountleads_association
```

You can combine the two by using the $expand query option:

```
    http://crmserver/MyOrgName/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet(guid'5B19D04F-C48E-E111-92D4-00155D107003')$select=Name&$expand=accountleads_association
```

More details on OData query options [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309461.aspx)